# Bootstrap datepicker not opening in custom lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a custom lightbox and trying to run the bootstrap datepicker within lightbox area, but the datepicker is showing behind the lightbox, Can somebody please suggest a fix for this?

Here is the [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrt54jg4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //open lightbox
    $(".ajaxLightbox").click(function() {
        $(".ajaxLightboxWrapper").fadeIn();
    });
    //close lightbox
 $(".ajaxLightBoxClose, .ajaxLightboxLayer").click(function() {
        $(".ajaxLightboxWrapper").fadeOut();
    });
 //open datepicker
    $('#counselling-datepicker-lightbox').datepicker({
        autoclose: true
    });
});
```

```css
.ajaxLightboxWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.ajaxLightboxContent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: -250px auto 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ajaxLightboxInner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.ajaxLightboxLayer {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.ajaxLightBoxClose {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" class="ajaxLightbox">Datepicker in lightbox</a></p>
<div class="ajaxLightboxWrapper">
  <div class="ajaxLightboxContent">
    <div class="ajaxLightBoxClose">X</div>
    <div class="ajaxLightboxInner" style="position:relative;"> 
     <input type="text" id="counselling-datepicker-lightbox" style="border:1px solid #000; padding:5px;">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ajaxLightboxLayer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a first lookup, it seems issue is with your modal popup(light box). if you render it normaly, it works fine

Comment: Yes, it works fine when the datepicker is from page, but when I place it in lightbox then not, I tried making the lightbox div position:relative as well but luck yet.

Comment: Doesn't Bootstrap datepicker require Bootstrap css?

Comment: @MarcusH Not sure, but when I add bootstrap it doesn't change anything

Comment: Added the bootstrap reference and it works. Added answer with fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide proper container to render it correctly in your custom modal box.
i gave ID to your **ajaxLightboxInner** and specified it as container in date input textbox. `data-date-container='#ajaxLightboxInner'`

```
<p><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ajaxLightbox">Datepicker in lightbox</a></p>
<div class="ajaxLightboxWrapper" id="mymodal">
  <div class="ajaxLightboxContent">
    <div class="ajaxLightBoxClose">X</div>
    <div class="ajaxLightboxInner" id="ajaxLightboxInner"> 
        <input type="text" id="counselling-datepicker-lightbox" data-date-container='#ajaxLightboxInner'>

     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ajaxLightboxLayer">


  </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    //open lightbox
    $(".ajaxLightbox").click(function() {
        $(".ajaxLightboxWrapper").fadeIn();
        $('#counselling-datepicker-lightbox').datepicker({
        autoclose: true
    });
    });
    //close lightbox
    $(".ajaxLightBoxClose, .ajaxLightboxLayer").click(function() {
        $(".ajaxLightboxWrapper").fadeOut();
    });
    //open datepicker

  $("#btn").click(function(){


  });

});
```

**[Link to updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrt54jg4/22/)**

Answer (score 1):

K D has a better approach towards solution. But if you want to stick with your code then. You have to play with z-index. Or you can also customize Bootstrap Datepicker CSS for your own custom usage.

I have quite obtain what you need Please look at this
[`https://jsfiddle.net/Lrt54jg4/19/`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrt54jg4/19/)

```
    <p><a href="#" class="ajaxLightbox" style="z-index:-1;">Datepicker in lightbox</a></p>
<div class="ajaxLightboxWrapper" style="z-index:-1;">
  <div class="ajaxLightboxContent">
    <div class="ajaxLightBoxClose">X</div>
    <div class="ajaxLightboxInner" style="position:relative;"> 
        <input type="text" id="counselling-datepicker-lightbox" style="border:1px solid #000; padding:5px;">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ajaxLightboxLayer"></div>
</div>
```

But i would recommend to customize datepicker css as it will give you more control.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I select KD's option because it was easy to handle as the way suggest!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the Bootstrap css reference

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css
```

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/64036raf/)